How can I update a WordPress website with content stored in a Dataverse table?
I have data stored in a Dataverse table that gets updated daily and all I want to do is update a website with that information.
I have tried using Zapier but beyond just the following I am a little lost;

I have also tried making a power bi dashboard with the updated table which works fine and then pasting the HTML that came from file > Embed report > Publish to Web.
However when I do that I get this annoying bar at the bottom of the report which I cannot seem to get rid of;


You can’t get rid of the bar in publish to web, it’s one of it’s limitations

Is there a way I can instead updates the website with a table with the data in it from a dataverse database as that is where the information is stored instead of using Power BI?
